# Parameters for QgsNMEAConnection

Tags: 3d, gps, qgis

I'm trying to write some quick and nasty code to write elevations to the geometry of a 3D point shapefile. Others have noted that this function is missing in the GPS Information Panel function. However, I can't find a list of parameters to use for the QgsNMEAConnection to connect to a GPS via the serial port, for example COM7. Can somebody help me this function, I can see it should have a 'host' and 'port' but can't figure out the other parameters. The following is an outline of the function. Don't be too harsh I'm new to QGIS and python. Another thing I can't do is open the attribute pop up table once a new point has been added.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# check the layer is a 3D point shapefile
# check the layer is editable

# the following line of code is WRONG. I need an example
# of the connection parameters to a GPS to a serial port eg COM7
c = QgsNMEAConnection(host="serial", port=7, "")

i=c.currentGPSInformation()

lat = i.latitude
lon = i.longitude
elv = i.elevation
wkt = '%s %f %s %f %s %f %s' %('Point(', lat, ' ', lon, ' ' , elv, ')')

feat = QgsFeature(layer.pendingFields())
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(wkt))
(res, outFeats) = layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feat])
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the following post:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188002/connect-disconnect-gps-device-via-pyqgis

I've been able to re-write my code so I know that the idea will work. I can now start to improve it with more robust code. Does anybody know how to open the attribute editor popup using python after adding new feature? Here's the updated code to add 3D geometry to a 3D shapefile.

```
# Connect to the GPS using the GPS Information Panel before running this code
# Select a 3D shapefile to add data to
# This code uses the connection from the GPS Info Panel and its data

layer = iface.activeLayer()

# check the layer is a 3D point shapefile
# check the layer is editable

connectionRegistry = QgsGPSConnectionRegistry().instance()
connectionList = connectionRegistry.connectionList()
GPSInfo = connectionList[0].currentGPSInformation()

lat = GPSInfo.latitude
lon = GPSInfo.longitude
elv = GPSInfo.elevation
wkt = '%s %f %s %f %s %f %s' %('Point(', lon, ' ', lat, ' ' , elv, ')')

feat = QgsFeature(layer.pendingFields())
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(wkt))
(res, outFeats) = layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feat])
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```